# spark-mapwithstate Why does the number of storage spaces remain 20?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, bigdata

I am using spark mapwithstate, but the storage space continues to grow.

[image]

***Question 1.***

MapPartitionsRDD Size in Memory 9GB x 20 Can you reduce this size?

**Question 2.**

```
And in InternalMapWithStateDStream, storagelevel is fixed to MEMORY_ONLY.
```

I want to change to persist (StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER) because of its size. Is it possible?

**Question 3.**

```
Private [streaming] object InternalMapWithStateDStream {
  Private val DEFAULT_CHECKPOINT_DURATION_MULTIPLIER = 10
}
```

I want to reduce this checkpoint value. Is it possible?

Comment: Hi , did you find the solution to this? i am facing the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> MapPartitionsRDD Size in Memory 9GB x 20 Can you reduce this size?

It's 9GB x 20, but how is it distributed across your cluster? You need to click the RDDs name to see the distributed state. If you want to reduce the in memory size, you'll need to think of an efficient way to represent your data.

> I want to change to persist (StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER) because of
>   its size. Is it possible?

No, you can't override the in-memory settings of the `MapWithStateDStream`.

> I want to reduce this checkpoint value. Is it possible?

Yes, you can set the `DStream`s checkpoint interval:

```
dStream.mapWithState(spec).checkpoint(Seconds(4))
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. **1. The cluster is well distributed.** But you only need the last state storage, why do you have the remaining 19 storage? **dStream.mapWithState(spec).checkpoint(Seconds(4))** not working Runs by default 10 interva        `val kafkastateStream = chnlStream.mapWithState(stateSpec)
      kafkastateStream.checkpoint(Seconds(10 * 5))
      val kafkaSnapshotStream = kafkastateStream.stateSnapshots()`

Comment: @HyunkeunLee *But you only need the last state storage, why do you have the remaining 19 storage?* That entirely depends on how you store the state. Does the incoming state have *different keys*? Do you store new state on each iteration? Show us the code. Regarding the checkpoint, it should run every `batch time *default interval* if it's not using your custom interval.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4065056/hyunkeun-lee : Hi , did you find the solution ? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

`MapWithState` also caches `mappedValues`, so you can also reduce the batch interval to reduce the size of cached RDDs.